# Blazor with php style url parameters ( ?parameter= )

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am building a web application for Envato using their authentication [API](https://build.envato.com/api#oauth)

Basically when the user login using **Envato**, they get redirected by Envato to

```
myapplink.com?code=1234-qwerty-login-code
```

In my app side I should use this code parameter to send a request to the API to get the access token for that user.

I am new to Blazor (server) the only way I know and I have tried to access Blazor url parameters is by `myapplink.com/login/parameter` I have tried to use the php style parameter (e.g `myapplink.com/login/?parameter=value`) but it seems that it's not recognized .

In my razor component I have

`Authentication.razor`

```html
@page "/authentication/{code?}"

<PageTitle>APP | Authentication</PageTitle>

<div>Some html to render the component</div>
```

the component base is something like

`Authentication.razor.cs`

```cs
public partial class Authentication
{
    [Parameter]
    public string? Code { get; set; }
    
    private async Task Authenticate()
    {

    }
}
```

I am able to access the parameter using

```
myapplink.com/authentication/code-123-qwerty
```

**My question**: how can I access the parameter using a PHP style url parameters (`myapplink.com/login/?cose=value`)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 6 you can use the `[SupplyParameterFromQuery]` attribute

It would look something like this:

```
[Parameter, SupplyParameterFromQuery]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse query strings in your Razor component. The route directive must be

```
@page "/authentication"
```

and inside `OnInitialized` method you have to fetch values from the query string passed to the page.

Check https://chrissainty.com/working-with-query-strings-in-blazor/ to get detail information.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for , Thanks for your help 

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Farzan Hajian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1635371/farzan-hajian) answer,

I was able to solve it following these step :

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` using nuget package manager
2. Add `@inject NavigationManager NavManager` to the `blazor component`

```html
@page "/authentication/{code?}"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>App | Authentication</PageTitle>
```

3. and finally get the `code` parameter in `OnInitialized`

```cs
    [Parameter]
    public string? Code { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var uri = NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavManager.Uri);
        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("code", out var _code))
        {
            Code = Convert.ToString(_code);
        }
    }
```